# Build classpath from JAR inside a WAR file

Tags: java, war, reflections

I am trying to dynamically extract configuration from a given WAR file.
My goal is to find all class that implement some interface (`Parameter`).

The war file is not on the classpath, so I create a temporary classloader to inspect its classes.

```
URL webClasses = new URL("jar","","file:" + new File(path).getAbsolutePath() + "!/WEB-INF/classes/");
URLClassLoader cl = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] { webClasses });
Reflections reflections = new Reflections(ClasspathHelper.forClassLoader(cl), new SubTypesScanner(), cl);
Set<Class<? extends Parameter>> params = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Parameter.class);
```

This works fine. I find all the implementation of `Parameter` in my webapp.

Now, I would like to do the same for each jar present in `WEB-INF/lib`.
Unfortunatelly I have not found a way to build the classloader in that case. The classloader seems to ignore [jar URLs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/JarURLConnection.html) (`jar:<url>!/WEB-INF/lib/{entry}.jar`).

When I run the code below, there is no class found by [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections):

```
Set<URL> libs = findLibJars(warUrl));
// The URLs are in the following format : {myWar}.war!/WEB-INF/lib/{myLib}.jar
URLClassLoader cl = URLClassLoader.newInstance(urls.toArray(new URL[urls.size()]));
cl.loadClass("my.company.config.AppParameter");
```

If possible, I would like to avoid having to extract `WEB-INF/lib/*.jar` from the WAR file and analyze them separately.

I am missing something here ? (other way to do it, other way to create the classloader, ... any lead would help). Maybe this can be done without using the Reflections library ?

Comment: Usually a servlet based web server would unzip the war file and then you have them all in some subfolder. Wouldn't it be easier to work with the extracted files?

Comment: I admit this is mostly curiosity that pushes me to search for such a solution. Extracting the files is indeed a way I know would work but since the purpose is purely to inspect the war and discover some configuration data. I would like this action to be fast (by filtering by package for instance since only package starting with my.company will potentially contains the classes I am looking for). In case the War file contains many third party dependencies, it would be a waste to extract, then delete them

Comment: but isn't it already deployed? Then the files should be there. A "war" is just a zip file.

Comment: Unfortunately my inspection process takes places before deployment. That is why the WAR file is not even in the classpath. I create a separate classloader to inpect it. I know a war file is zipped but the JAR URL is a java specificity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is certainly possible. Here is an ugly example of doing it:

```
String warName = "wlaj.war";
ClassLoader loader = new ClassLoader() {
    @Override
    protected Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        // This probably needs fixing:
        String fileName = name.replace('.', '/') + ".class";
        try {
            try (ZipFile zf = new ZipFile(warName)) {
                ZipEntry jar = zf.getEntry("WEB-INF/lib/jlaj.jar");
                if (jar == null)
                    throw new ClassNotFoundException("No jlaj.jar");
                try (ZipInputStream jarInput = new ZipInputStream(zf.getInputStream(jar))) {
                    for (ZipEntry cl; (cl = jarInput.getNextEntry()) != null; ) {
                        if (fileName.equals(cl.getName())) {
                            ByteArrayOutputStream data = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                            for (int len; (len = jarInput.read(buffer)) != -1; ) {
                                data.write(buffer, 0, len);
                            }
                            buffer = data.toByteArray();
                            return defineClass(name, buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            throw new ClassNotFoundException();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new ClassNotFoundException("Error opening class file", ex);
        }
    }
};
loader.loadClass("jlaj.NewJFrame");
```

The problems:

1. Need an elegant foolproof way to convert a class name into the file path inside the JAR. In my case `"jlaj.NewJFrame" -> "jlaj/NewJFrame.class"`, but it gets very ugly when trying to load inner classes and maybe in some other situations I can't even think about.
2. Reading the class data should probably belong to some utility `readAll` method because it looks very messy.
3. Obviously this needs a non-anonymous class with both WAR name and inner JAR name passed to the constructor. Or `ZipFile` and `ZipEntry`, if you want to iterate over those externally.

On the positive side, it works.

Comment: It works indeed, unfortunately the Reflections library apparently relies on URL classloaders only, so I had to write the search method myself which is probably less efficient but perfectly fits my need for now. Thank you

Comment: I am not sure that your solution is realy very ugluy becose a found the same code in URLClassLoader class:
 String path = name.replace('.', '/').concat(".class");

: )